# path-dependent first hitting time

Tags: stochastic-processes

For an SDE
$$
\mathrm{d}X_t = b(X_t) \, \mathrm{d}t + \epsilon \, a(X_t) \, \mathrm{d}W_t \tag{1}
$$
where $\mathrm{d}W_t$ is a $d$-dimensional vector of independent Wiener processes and $\epsilon > 0$ is small, consider the first hitting time
$$
\tau_{\partial D} := \inf \{t > 0 : X_t \in \partial D\} \tag{2}
$$
where $D$ is some domain with boundary $\partial D$. For this problem, there are results from large deviation theory (starting with Freidlin-Wentzell) that describe statistics of $\tau$.

---

From the same setup as (1), consider the modified hitting time problem
$$
\tau_{\partial D | \lnot C} := \inf \{t > 0 : (X_t \in \partial D) \land (X_t \notin C\, \forall t)\} \tag{3}
$$
where $C \subset D$ is some region of the space that we want the process to avoid.

---

Two questions:

1. Is $\tau_{\partial D | \lnot C}$ computed by finding the Freidlin-Wentzell action functional (ensuring that the pathway avoids $C$)?
2. If not, is there theory handling (3)?